# Print pandas row in a single string (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, pandas

This code:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.loc[0], df.loc[1])
```

Gives next output:

```
col1    1
col2    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64 col1    2
col2    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

But I want something like that (because I want to print a lot of pairs of rows in a cycle from two different dataframes):

```
1 3, 2 4
```

Notice that I want to see output *in a single row*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for convert `Series` to `1d numpy array`:

```
print(df.loc[0].values, df.loc[1].values)
[1 3] [2 4]
```

Or convert to `list`s:

```
print(df.loc[0].values.tolist(), df.loc[1].values.tolist())
[1, 3] [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the numpy array to `str`, and then replace brackets & newlines

This will work generally for dataframes with multiple rows

```
import re
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
re.sub(r']|\[', '', str(df.values).replace('\n',','))
# outputs:
'1 3, 2 4'
```